# Spring: Run BeanPostProcessor on maniually created bean

Tags: java, spring

I'm manually autowiring fields on an object which is not created by Spring. I have 2 custom `BeanPostProcessors` that should also be applied to this object. However the ObjectFactory seems not to take care of this. I'm using the following snippet:

```
ApplicationContext context = ...;
context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(this);
```

The autowire fields are processed correctly but my 2 post processors are not invoked here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal `BeanPostProcessor` allows to replace the bean by returning a different object. There is no way to implement this behavior in a meaningful manner for already existing objects. I guess that's why Spring chose not to call the post processors after manual injection.

Inspecting the autowiring code I found out that there is an extension called `InstantiationAwareBeanPostProcessor`. It provides additional call backs which are also called after manual autowiring (for example `postProcessAfterInstantiation`).

Answer (score 0):

`AutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBean` performs autowiring on an already existant bean omitting any pre- or postprocessing. If you need that, please use `AutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowire` or AutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean instead.

Comment: My question was how I can achieve such a behavior for existing objects because I have no control over the creation of the object on which I want to perform injection.